# How to set a center rotation position using the cgscenegraph framework

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, frameworks, javascript-framework

i want to make a rotation on a node with a starting position set to its center, but the animate function take the top left corner of my node.....

i have something like that :

```
sceneGraph.animate(circleNode, "rotation.angle", 400, 0, 2, "linear", 0, true);
```

could you help me ?

thx,

Comment: What is `sceneGraph` or `animate()`? Is that jQuery's `animate()`?

Comment: Hello Cerbrus, i'm developping a little game and i found this html5 canvas framework : cgscenegraph at http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the rotation point of a node by using the rotationCenter property of the node.

Example:
    MyNode.rotationCenter = new CGSGPosition (0.5, 0.5);

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: yes, it's good ! thank you !!! now, i can create a spinner for my loading state ;)